# pexpect kind of operation with ansible

Tags: ansible, pexpect

I am looking to automate an interactive install process with ansible. This install does not have a silent install option or does not take command line arguments for the interactive questions. The question involve setting a folder location, making sure folder location is right etc for which answers might be default or custom. 
I looked into the `expect` module of ansible but seems like it does not solve my purpose.

```
- expect:
command: passwd username
responses:
  (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
```

I don't need the command but it's required. Instead I am looking for something that could regex `Are you sure you want to continue [y|n]? [n]:` for which I want to send the default out `By sending return or typing n as a response` and for example `Backup directory [/tmp]` for which the response would be `Carriage return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way that works for me. I piped in the arguments to the shell script which when run manually needs the answers. Like `./shell.sh <<< 'answer1\nanswer2\n'` which works perfectly for me. This I have added to the task.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need the command but it's required. Instead I am looking for something that could regex `Are you sure you want to continue [y|n]? [n]:`

[The module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) requires a `command` because you have to run *something* to get any output.

You obviously do have a command in mind, because you've run it manually and seen the output it produces.  That's what you should be plugging into the module.

Alternatively, you can write a [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) script yourself and use the `command` or `shell` modules to run it.